# How to generate multiple jmeter sampler results from a BSF Sampler?

Tags: jmeter

I have a BSF sampler that runs a groovy script.
I want to create multiple sample results out of this single script in jmeter.
Is it possible?

Comment: Ca you clarify what you want to do, what will files contain

Comment: For example my groovy script will run a junit suite and i want to report each junit test separately. Or my groovy script will make 100 http get and i want to display 100 sampler results. This is a genral question about how to generate many sampler reports from a single script sampler like groovy or java script

Answer (score 0):

> ...my groovy script will run a junit suite and i want to report each junit test separately. Or my groovy script will make 100 http get and i want to display 100 sampler results.

1. To achieve this you have to organize loop - e.g. put your BSF Sampler under any suitable [logic controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers): [Loop Controller)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller), [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller), [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller), or use possibilities of [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) (Loop Count, Number of Threads fields).
   This scenario will re-use single instance of your BSF Sampler for each new iteration / thread and produce separate sampler result for each execution.
2. As well you possibly have to provide different entry data / params to BSF Sampler on each iteration - to parametrize it. In this case you can look at least into [CSV Dataset Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) (to read from file) or any of [postprocessors/extractors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) (go get data from responses).
3. Suppose you also look into [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to use along with groovy scripts for better performance.